# How to write a test to check invalid configuration causes Spring application context to fail?

Tags: java, spring, testing

Our team writes tests for Spring using Spring's [TestContext framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-framework).

It is really easy to use, but I cannot find a way to test invalid context configuration.

I tried putting `@Test(expected = Exception.class)` on the test with the invalid config, and the test failed anyways with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`.

Answer (score 0):

To test a failure I usually do the following in negative tests:

```
try{
    //code that should cause exception
    fail(); //or equivalent for your test framework
}catch(Exception e){ //your exception type can be more specific if you want
    // code that examines exception and confirms it's expected (if any)
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion, but this is a pattern I already use and it does not help in this case. The problem is Spring TextContext is used as a JUnit test runner so if the configuration is invalid, the test won't get touched at all. I was kind of hoping it would do the context initialization as part of running a test, but it is not and errors are not captured by `@Test(expected=Exception` annotation.

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand that.  Hmm, you may have to programmatically create a context from the invalid config.

Comment: Ah, yes. Why didn't I thought of that.